# How can I make Vim recognize .md files simply as Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vim

I mean, that's really the whole question... I need the auto-indentation on newline insertion and syntax highlighting, and perhaps there are other niceties that I take for granted but would miss if absent.

That's all.

Comment: found this link by copying and pasting your question in google lol.....http://beerpla.net/2008/04/02/how-to-add-a-vim-file-extension-to-syntax-highlighting/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [a `vim` plugin specifically for Markdown](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown), but if you really want to use JS specifically you can use

```
autocmd FileType md set filetype=javascript
```